# `Confirm Form Resubmission` issue on page rendered thru app.post('/', in expressjs

Tags: html, node.js, rest, express

html contains

```
form(name="Form", action="/", method="post")
  button(type='submit') submit
```

Express server contains:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){   
  res.render('home', {user: req.body});
});
```

As expected the `home.jade` is rendered in the browser. But when I refresh the `home.jade` file at `http://localhost:3000` It asks for **Confirm Form Resubmission** I want to get rid of this - `Confirm Form Resubmission`!

The `home.jade` file is simple file containing simple text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn't really caused by your code, but by that browsers want to do a post again when you've received a response from a POST. A common way to solve this issue is to redirect to the same page.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){   
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Now when you refresh the browser will refetch a GET '/' instead.

**Update to reflect updated question**

To render data that was posted on the redirected page, one can use sessions.

```
app.use(express.cookieSession());

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  req.session.user = req.body;
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

And in the middleware for GET '/' you have to make sure to use that parameter

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('home', { user: req.session.user });
});
```

Comment: how do i pass `{user: req.body}` thru this arrangement?

Comment: Ah that wasn't in the original question was it? The cleanest way would be to use sessions, I'll update my answer.